# Decompress incoming HTTP SOAP requests in ASMX

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I'm trying to get IIS to accept compressed SOAP/XML *requests*.

It seems that IIS does not support compressed HTTP *requests* out of the box. Any HTTP request with `Content-Encoding: gzip` or `deflate` returns HTTP error 400.

So I tried to add a `DelegatingHandler` via **Global.asax** as described in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263651/delegatinghandler-to-decompress-incoming-requests-in-webapi):

**Global.asax**:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new DecompressionHandler());
}
```

But in case of **ASMX** no MessageHandlers seem to be executed (I've checked,  `Application_Start` *is* invoked, but the whole WebApi configuration seems to have no effect in ASMX).

So the question is - how to implement **SOAP** request decompression in an **ASMX** service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get it to work with a `SoapExtension`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;

/// <summary>
///   ASPX SOAP request decompression WebMethod annotation
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CompressedRequestAttribute : SoapExtensionAttribute
{
  public override Type ExtensionType { get { return typeof(CompressedRequestExtension); } }
  public override int Priority { get { return 0; } set { } }
}

/// <summary>
///   ASPX SOAP request decompression implementation
/// </summary>
public class CompressedRequestExtension : SoapExtension
{
  public override object GetInitializer(Type serviceType) { return null; }

  public override object GetInitializer(LogicalMethodInfo methodInfo, SoapExtensionAttribute attribute) { return null; }

  public override void Initialize(object initializer) { }

  Stream origStream;
  StreamDelegate wrappedStream = new StreamDelegate();

  public override void ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message) {
    switch (message.Stage) {
      case SoapMessageStage.BeforeDeserialize:
        if (message.ContentEncoding == "gzip") {
          wrappedStream.wrapped = new GZipStream(origStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true);
          message.ContentEncoding = null;
        }
        else if (message.ContentEncoding == "deflate") {
          wrappedStream.wrapped = new DeflateStream(origStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true);
          message.ContentEncoding = null;
        }
        else {
          goto default;
        }
        break;
      default:
        wrappedStream.wrapped = origStream;
        break;
    }
  }

  public override Stream ChainStream(Stream stream) {
    origStream = stream;
    return wrappedStream;
  }

}

public class StreamDelegate : Stream
{
  public Stream wrapped;
  public override bool CanRead { get { return wrapped.CanRead; } }
  public override bool CanSeek { get { return wrapped.CanSeek; } }
  public override bool CanWrite { get { return wrapped.CanWrite; } }
  public override long Length { get { return wrapped.Length; } }
  public override long Position { get { return wrapped.Position; } set { wrapped.Position = value; } }
  public override void Flush() { wrapped.Flush(); }
  public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) { return wrapped.Read(buffer, offset, count); }
  public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) { return wrapped.Seek(offset, origin); }
  public override void SetLength(long value) { wrapped.SetLength(value); }
  public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) { wrapped.Write(buffer, offset, count); }
}
```

And then annotate each `WebMethod` with:

```
  [CompressedRequestAttribute]
```

---

And a proof that it works:

```
POST /TestService/TestAction1.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
SOAPAction: http://example.com/TestService:action1
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 321

<gzipped-request>

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 10193

<gzipped-response>
```